# Chrome Dev - custom location imp/exp

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Anyone know if you are able to export/import custom locations (the latitude/longitude) from one PC to another from Google Chrome? I had a list of custom locations and can't find a way to do this. Also tried to look if there was a log file or anything that I could copy/paste over.

Looked for native options in the browser, googled options, and looked at the setup files to see if there was a log of sorts.